# Google maps address and map display (exceed limit image)

Tags: php, google-maps, web, dictionary, geolocation

I have following problem. I'm using google maps in php to get the address of latitude and longitude and a map snapshot of this location.

To obtain address I use following code:

```
// INITIALIZING CURL
$returnValue = NULL;
$ch = curl_init();

// SERVICE CALL
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$lat.",".$lon."&sensor=false";

// SETTING PARAMS OF CURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

// GETTING AND RESULTING RESULT
$result_part = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($result_part, TRUE);
```

And I parse obtained JSON as follows:

```
// PARSING RESULTS FROM JSON
if (isset($json['results'])) {
    foreach    ($json['results'] as $result_part) {
        foreach ($result_part['address_components'] as $address_component) {
            $types = $address_component['types'];
            // GETTING STREET
            if (in_array('route', $types)) {
                $addr = $address_component['long_name'];
            }
            // GETTING STREET NUMBER
            if (in_array('street_number', $types)) {
                $number = $address_component['long_name'];
            }
            // GETTING COUNTRY
            if (in_array('country', $types)) {
                $country = $address_component['long_name'];
            }
            // GETTING POSTAL CODE
            if (in_array('postal_code', $types)) {
                $postal_code = $address_component['long_name'];
            }
            // GETTING CITY
            if (in_array('locality', $types)) {
                $city = $address_component['long_name'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine but sometimes the address is not obtained. It looks like some overload of requests but I dont understand why because the site that I'm programming is not accessible yet for other people.

Other problem connected to this is the map snapshots. Here is the code:

```
<? echo "<a href = \"https://maps.google.com/maps?q=".$lat.",".$lon."\" target=\"_blank\">" ?>
<? echo "<img src=\"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" . $lat . "," . $lon . "&zoom=16&size=200x200&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:I%7C" . $lat . "," . $lon . "&sensor=false\" alt=\"google maps\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\" /></a>" ?>
```

This works also fine but sometimes I obtain image like this:

[image]

I doubt that I exceeded the limit.

Any ideas ? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: ` I doubt that I exceeded the limit. Any ideas ?` is this on a shared webhost (like RackSpace)?

Comment: no it's not on such shared webhost. It's on own webserver - but this web is used also for the webpage of a company. Is it possible that google controlls access of all people of that company via one IP ? I meaan whole group of users connected on that IP

Comment: and than it blocks the map service because of too many requests  ?

Comment: That is [certainly possible](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=en#Limits).  It doesn't look like you are using [an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=en#api_key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @geocodezip has suggested it could be because of not using a key.

Also as per the reverse geocoding documentation on :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

> Note: Reverse geocoding is an estimate. The geocoder will attempt to find the closest addressable location within a certain tolerance; if no match is found, the geocoder will return zero results.